# Proving equality of types depending on (further) proofs

Tags: idris, dependent-type

Suppose we'd like to have a "proper" `minus` on `Nat`s, requiring `m <= n` for `` n `minus` m `` to make sense:

```
%hide minus

minus : (n, m : Nat) -> { auto prf : m `LTE` n } -> Nat
minus { prf = LTEZero } n Z = n
minus { prf = LTESucc prevPrf } (S n) (S m) = minus n m
```

Now let's try to prove the following lemma, stating that `(n + (1 + m)) - k = ((1 + n) + m) - k`, assuming both sides are valid:

```
minusPlusTossS : (n, m, k : Nat) ->
                 { auto prf1 : k `LTE` n + S m } ->
                 { auto prf2 : k `LTE` S n + m } ->
                 minus (n + S m) k = minus (S n + m) k
```

The goal suggests the following sublemma might help:

```
plusTossS : (n, m : Nat) -> n + S m = S n + m
plusTossS Z m = Refl
plusTossS (S n) m = cong $ plusTossS n m
```

so we try to use it:

```
minusPlusTossS n m k =
  let tossPrf = plusTossS n m
  in rewrite tossPrf in ?rhs
```

And here we fail:

```
When checking right hand side of minusPlusTossS with expected type
        minus (n + S m) k = minus (S n + m) k

When checking argument prf to function Main.minus:
        Type mismatch between
                LTE k (S n + m) (Type of prf2)
        and
                LTE k replaced (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        S (plus n m)
                and
                        replaced
```

If I understand this error correctly, it just means that it tries to rewrite the RHS of the target equality (which is `minus { prf = prf2 } (S n + m) k`) to `minus { prf = prf2 } (n + S m) k` and fails. Rightfully, of course, since `prf` is a proof for a different inequality! And while `replace` could be used to produce a proof of `(S n + m) k` (or `prf1` would do as well), it does not look like it's possible to simultaneously rewrite and change the proof object so that it matches the rewrite.

How do I work around this? Or, more generally, how do I prove this lemma?

Comment: Maybe you can include your proof for `plusTossS` so people can better reproduce your code.

Comment: You probably need to do something intelligent with the proofs:

```
minusPlusTossS n m Z {prf1 = LTEZero} {prf2 = LTEZero} = let tossPrf = plusTossS n m
  in rewrite tossPrf in Refl
```

typechecks, but is not total.

Comment: @Markus I guess that's due to the fact that the type checker cannot match ``k `LTE` n + S m`` against the available form for `LTESucc`. Sure, we could rewrite that proof into ``k `LTE` S (n + m)``, but that was not particularly fruitful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I guess I solved it. Bottom line: if you don't know what to do, do a lemma!

So we have a proof of two minuends `n1, n2` being equal, and we need to produce a proof of `` n1 `minus` m = n2 `minus` m ``. Let's write this down!

```
minusReflLeft : { n1, n2, m : Nat } -> (prf : n1 = n2) -> (prf_n1 : m `LTE` n1) -> (prf_n2 : m `LTE` n2) -> n1 `minus` m = n2 `minus` m
minusReflLeft Refl LTEZero LTEZero = Refl
minusReflLeft Refl (LTESucc prev1) (LTESucc prev2) = minusReflLeft Refl prev1 prev2
```

I don't even need `plusTossS` anymore, which can be replaced by a more directly applicable lemma:

```
plusRightS : (n, m : Nat) -> n + S m = S (n + m)
plusRightS Z m = Refl
plusRightS (S n) m = cong $ plusRightS n m
```

After that, the original one becomes trivial:

```
minusPlusTossS : (n, m, k : Nat) ->
                 { auto prf1 : k `LTE` n + S m } ->
                 { auto prf2 : k `LTE` S n + m } ->
                 minus (n + S m) k = minus (S n + m) k
minusPlusTossS {prf1} {prf2} n m k = minusReflLeft (plusRightS n m) prf1 prf2
```